# Ionic1 doesn't compile

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, build, compilation, emulation

Help me please!

I am working with a project made in Ionic 1, when I compile it it shows me the following message and does not save the changes … Any ideas?

```
[WARN] Not performing Ionic build for project type: ionic1.

cordova build ios
```

Thankss!!

Comment: can you give your environment information using `ionic info` command

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo npm uninstall -g ionic
sudo npm install -g ionic@2.3.0
```